# JMeter logic in HTTP and JDBC request

Tags: postgresql, jmeter

I have a HTTP and JDBC request. The objective is to run the HTTP request and JDBC will insert the result into postgreSQL.
Individually, HTTP request is successfully and JDBC request is inserting the results into table but while running both in same test plan, insert is not working.

Thanks

Run both request and insert results in postgreSQL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing the problem details, i.e.

- can you identify the error using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener?
- are there any suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- is the query visible in [PostgreSQL query log](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-log-queries-in-postgresql/)

In general JMeter's [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically CSV files so you can first run HTTP Request sampler with the concurrency and workload pattern you need and after execution finishes you will [import the .jtl file into Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)

In case if you need to insert a special value from the response you can write the values to the file using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property and [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)